# Installation of Android x86 not working properly

Tags: grub, android

I installed today the latest version of Android x86 OS on a old HP Compaq Mini 700 el, from USB key, after checking that everything worked with the live boot.

Installation was rather tricky and I'm not surprised I failed in doing so, since at reboot I faced a black screen with >tGRUB laying there, impossible to modify or write on.

Any idea of what I'm supposed to do? I've read I messed with the partitions, but I don't know how to fix those. If anyone knew how to help me, please do so with step by step instructions...

Thank you all for your attention!

How do I create the partitions? :(

Comment: Questions about niche OSs should be directed to the dev team and distro builders in the 1st place.